# Javascript, result from API emtpy on Promise with then

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have this code:

```
const https = require('https');

async function getUsernames(threshold) {
    let result = [];
    https.get(endpoint, (res) => {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        let body = '';
        res.on('data', data => {
            body += data;
        })
        res.on('end', () => {
            result = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log('result', result); //show data
        })
        
        return result;
    });
}

async function main() {
    const res = await getUsernames(2);
    console.log('res', res);
}

main();
```

I have that line `console.log('result', result); //show data` where I can see the result coming from the API, but oin the console.log inside the main() function is not returning, I get undefined, why?

Comment: I don't get it, with `return` I see only the object properties of the promise

Comment: This is not going to work (and neither will the commenter's suggestion). `https.get()` is a callback-based API, and async/await only works with promises. You first need to convert the callback API to a promise-based API, or switch to a http library that natively does promises.

Comment: Can not use a library, fetch, nor web libraries like xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 2):

```js
const https = require('https');

async function getUsernames(threshold) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      https.get(endpoint, (res) => {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        let body = '';
        res.on('data', data => {
            body += data;
        })
        res.on('end', () => {
            result = JSON.parse(body);
            resolve(result)
        })
    })
}

async function main() {
    const res = await getUsernames(2);
    console.log('res', res);
}

main();
```

Comment: thumbs up: was about to post this ^^